# Stetho inspection do not work

Tags: android, google-chrome, stetho

I want to debug android application with Stetho:

**BaseActivity.class**

```
 Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
    Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
            .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
            .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
            .build();
```

**grade.build**

```
   compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
   compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.1'
```

When i inspect from chrome://inspect i got nothing:
[image]

I enabled PTP USB Connection on physical android device (unrooted)

Hot to make Stetho works?

Comment: Do you come to this view by selecting your application on `chrome://inspect`? You have select `Elements` tab to see your application elements or in `Resources` tab select one item from the left menu to see the specific resource

Comment: What do you want to monitor by stetho? okhttp's http networks, view hierarchy or other things?

Comment: I want to lookup database records.

Surprisingly, after Ubuntu reboot stetho starts working.